# How do I reference one cell created in ARRAYFORMULA from another?

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I'm using `ARRAYFORMULA` to generate values (whitespace is for readability):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
  Sheet1!A1:C,
  Sheet1!A1:A * Sheet1:B1:B,
  Sheet1!A1:A * Sheet1:B1:B + Sheet1!C1:C
})
```

- The first 3 cells are directly from *Sheet1*.
- The 4th cell is a formula using the values from the first 2 cells.
- The 5th cell is a formula using the value from that 4th cell, and then adding the 3rd cell.

Instead of needing to re-calculate the 4th cell in the 5th cell, is there a way to reference the result of the 4th cell in the 5th cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to reference a column of virtual array `{}` within the same array. Two workarounds are:

- Create the column A*B+C using a second array formula, which references the output of the first

or,

- Wrap the output of arrayformula in a `query` which can reference the columns as Col1, Col2, ...

Example:

```
=query(arrayformula({A1:C, A1:A*B1:B}), "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col4+Col3 label Col4+Col3 ''", 0)
```

Comment: That's a very clever solution. Thank you!